# Can you redirect "http:example.com/folder" to http://www.example.com"?

Tags: html

Just wondering if this is possible to do?

Comment: Read this [htaccess](http://htaccess-guide.com/)

Answer (score 1):

You can use htaccess or a single HTML-File, that is located in the "folder" folder.

Just add an **index.html** file into the folder. Then add following code:

```
<!DOCKTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="refresh" content="0; url=http://example.com/" />
</head>
<body>
    You will be redirected...
</body>
</html>
```

The "0" in the meta tag defines the seconds after the visitor should be redirected. Type 5 if he should stay 5 seconds on page.

Answer (score 0):

Off course that is possible with numerous ways to achieve it.

Meta-refresh within the head of your body in /folder/:

```
<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="0; url=http://example.com/" />
```

Small javascript in the /folder/ redirecting to the root.

```
<script>window.location.href = '/'</script>
```

In PHP you can use

```
header('Location: /');
```

to redirect your visitor.

An otherway is to use htaccess' rewritemodule

```
Redirect /old_dir/ http://www.yourdomain.com/new_dir/index.html
```

or if you're using NginX an new location within your server will work:

```
rewrite ^(.*) http://www.example.com/$1 permanent;
```

So it really depends on what you want exaclty. If you know that some of the above solutions are better or even not valid.
For instance with the reqrite options (last two) you can tell spiders (google) that the page is permanently (301) or temporary (302) relocated.

Answer (score 0):

Web application server often load a default page, like index.html.
In your "folder" you could add an HTML page like this:

Absolute path:

```
<HTML>
   <HEAD>
       <META http-equiv="refresh" content="0; url=http://example.com" />
   </HEAD>
   </BODY>
   </BODY>
</HTML>
```

relative path:

```
<HTML>
   <HEAD>
       <META http-equiv="refresh" content="0; url=.." />
   </HEAD>
   </BODY>
   </BODY>
</HTML>
```

JS style:

```
<HTML>
   <HEAD>

   </HEAD>
   </BODY onload="document.location.href='..'">
   </BODY>
</HTML>
```